# Group by multiple columns in QGIS array

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, qgis-processing, grouping, group-layer

I'm looking to create a figure with multiple rule-based symbologies. A graduated range within a category within a main category.

The only way I think that's possible is by adding categories, ranges to the rule in the rule-based symbology menu. Unfortunately, the data is not grouped. I'd like to create an atlas so ideally would not like to make duplicates of the same layer.

[image]

Is there any way to group by (`"Aquifer"`, `"ChemNam"`, `"Conc0.5"`) in that particular order? I tried to use the array function:

```
array("Aquifer", "ChemNam", "Conc0.5)
```

but the string was too long.